# Как узнать сколько свободной оперативной памяти

Tags: java

На облачной тачке есть ощущения что не хватает оперативной памяти (но ни доступов до тачки, ни увеличить опертивы нет возможности)
Как узнать сколько памяти всего, и сколько свободно на данный момент?
Делаю так:

`long usedMBytes = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1048576;`

Но в ответе выходит 1486355940 мегабайт, на локальной машине (решил продебажить), но на локалке у меня всего 16 оперативы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приоритет математических операций не отменялся, поэтому у вас сначала было деление, потом вычитание.

Попробуйте:

```
long usedMBytes = (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()) / 1048576;
```